# PyCharm is failing to load the console

Tags: python, anaconda, pycharm

I have recently got a new laptop, installed the latest version of anaconda for python 3.7 and pycharm community edition on to it.

I created a virtual environment, started pycharm tried to run some code and then I received an error in the console

I then reinstalled anaconda and didn't create a venv but instead tried to execute code again and got the following error

```
C:\Users\chris.halliwell\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Users\chris.halliwell\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.2\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py" --mode=client --port=61636
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chris.halliwell\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.2\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 5, in <module>
    from _pydev_comm.rpc import make_rpc_client, start_rpc_server, start_rpc_server_and_make_client
  File "C:\Users\chris.halliwell\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\rpc.py", line 4, in <module>
    from _pydev_comm.server import TSingleThreadedServer
  File "C:\Users\chris.halliwell\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\server.py", line 4, in <module>
    from _shaded_thriftpy.server import TServer
  File "C:\Users\chris.halliwell\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.2\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\server.py", line 9, in <module>
    from _shaded_thriftpy.transport import (
  File "C:\Users\chris.halliwell\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.2\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\transport\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .sslsocket import TSSLSocket, TSSLServerSocket  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\chris.halliwell\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.2\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\transport\sslsocket.py", line 7, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "C:\Users\chris.halliwell\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is almost identical to the previous error I received (except the location isn't a venv)

What DLL am I missing? Did I setup one of my programs incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. The way I got round it is to load the anaconda prompt, and then run pycharm from within the prompt. It loads all the correct dependencies that way.

Comment: This does work, but I get a warning saying this is an illegal access operation and that in future releases this will be denied.